# How can I add separate bump maps to each channel in this splat map shader (Unity3D)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

I have this shader I use for splat mapping in Unity3D. It's a Frankenstein'd monster from a few different ones I found that I finally got to work. The problem is that it does not have the ability to have bump mapping on the textures.

I'd appreciate the help if someone can show me what to change/add to this shader code to give it the ability to have a separate bump map for each of the RGBA channel textures.

```
Shader "Custom/Texture Splatting" {

Properties {
    _MainTex ("Splat Map", 2D) = "white" {}
    [NoScaleOffset] _Texture1 ("R", 2D) = "white" {}
    [NoScaleOffset] _Texture2 ("G", 2D) = "white" {}
    [NoScaleOffset] _Texture3 ("B", 2D) = "white" {}
    [NoScaleOffset] _Texture4 ("A", 2D) = "white" {}
    _BumpMap1 ("BumpMapR", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _BumpMap2 ("BumpMapG", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _BumpMap3 ("BumpMapB", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _BumpMap4 ("BumpMapA", 2D) = "bump" {}
}

SubShader {

    Pass {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex MyVertexProgram
        #pragma fragment MyFragmentProgram

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        sampler2D _Texture1, _Texture2, _Texture3, _Texture4;

        struct VertexData {
            float4 position : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct Interpolators {
            float4 position : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uvSplat : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        Interpolators MyVertexProgram (VertexData v) {
            Interpolators i;
            i.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.position);
            i.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            i.uvSplat = v.uv;
            return i;
        }

        float4 MyFragmentProgram (Interpolators i) : SV_TARGET {
            float4 splat = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uvSplat);

            return
                tex2D(_Texture1, i.uv) * splat.r +
                tex2D(_Texture2, i.uv) * splat.g +
                tex2D(_Texture3, i.uv) * splat.b +
                tex2D(_Texture4, i.uv) * (1 - splat.r - splat.g - splat.b);
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Bump maps are normally used to influence how lighting behaves on a surface, adding the impression that the surface is not flat. However, your example above is an unlit vertex shader, it doesn't have any lighting simulation, so you can't just add bump maps, you first need to turn the shader into a lit shader. I'd suggest using a surface shader instead.

If you still want to use a vertex shader for lighting, that's a whole different research. You can see some explanations about that in this [Unity thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/adding-bump-map-to-shader.672844/), but I wouldn't recommend it unless you really need to:

That said, here's a splat surface shader that I made that uses splat map to blend two textures and includes a bump map. I suggest you adjust it to your needs (use 4 channels instead of 2) rather than trying to build a lit shader from scratch.

```
Shader "Custom/TerrainTwoTexturesBlend" {
    Properties {
        _Color("Tint", Color) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        _MainTex("Albedo", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BumpMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        _MainTex2("Albedo 2", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BumpMap2("Normal Map 2", 2D) = "bump" {}

        _Mask("Mask", 2D) = "white" {}

        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Specular ("Specular", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { 
            "Queue" = "Geometry-4"
            "RenderType" = "Opaque" 
            "PreviewType" = "Plane" 
            "ForceNoShadowCasting" = "True"
        }
        LOD 200

        ZWrite Off

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf StandardSpecular

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _BumpMap;

        sampler2D _MainTex2;
        sampler2D _BumpMap2;

        sampler2D _Mask;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex: TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv2_MainTex2: TEXCOORD2;
            float2 uv3_Mask: TEXCOORD1;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Specular;
        fixed4 _Color;

        // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
        // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
            // put more per-instance properties here
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandardSpecular o) {
            float2 uvterrain1 = IN.uv_MainTex;
            float2 uvterrain2 = IN.uv2_MainTex2;
            float2 uvmask = IN.uv3_Mask;

            fixed4 c1 = tex2D(_MainTex, uvterrain1);
            fixed4 n1 = tex2D(_BumpMap, uvterrain1);

            fixed4 c2 = tex2D(_MainTex2, uvterrain2);
            fixed4 n2 = tex2D(_BumpMap2, uvterrain2);

            fixed4 m = tex2D(_Mask, uvmask);

            o.Albedo = _Color * (c1 * m.r + c2 * (1 - m.r));

            float3 fn1 = UnpackScaleNormal(n1, _BumpScale);
            float3 fn2 = UnpackScaleNormal(n2, _BumpScale2);
            o.Normal = fn1 * m.r + fn2 * (1 - m.r);

            // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
            o.Specular = _Specular;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = 1;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out.